# Use Function with multi conditions on BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[studentinformation]
    (@name as varchar (50)= NULL
     @surname as varchar (50) = NULL
     @schoolsname as varchar = NULL)
RETURNS **NVARCHAR(255)** 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ret AS **NVARCHAR(255)** = NULL    

    --Condition 1
    SELECT @ret = name + " " + surname
    FROM dbo.dataset_red as rd WITH(NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN dbo.dataset_blue as bl WITH(NOLOCK) on rd.dataset = bl.dataset
    WHERE red.dataset IS NOT NULL

    IF @ret IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        RETURN @ret
    END

    --Condition 2
    SELECT @ret = name + " " + surname
    FROM dbo.dataset_red as rd WITH(NOLOCK)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.dataset_green as gr WITH(NOLOCK) on rd.zone = gr.zone
    WHERE red.dataset IS NOT NULL

    IF @ret IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        RETURN @ret
    END

    --Condition 3
    SELECT @ret = name + " " + surname
    FROM dbo.dataset_red as rd WITH(NOLOCK)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.dataset_yellow as yl WITH(NOLOCK) on rd.zone = yl.zone
    WHERE red.dataset IS NOT NULL

    RETURN @ret
END
```

Describe my question:

- I have function which is come from 3 condition that get value from different table.
- This function has hierarchical order from condition 1 to Condition 3.

My question:

- I need to convert this T-SQL function to BigQuery

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use! Otherwise, you might end up with parameters or variables that default to exactly ***ONE*** (1 !!!) character in length - usually *not* what you really want!

Comment: I have edited already, sorry to provide unclear question.

Answer (score 0):

To create a function with multiple conditions you can use `CASE` to check multiple conditions. Using this sample data I have 2 tables.

Table 1:

[image]

Table 2:

[image]

Consider the below approach where I made two conditions that will run a query when it returns a value. It will return null if don't match anything:

NOTE: Query below are for testing only and you can add more conditions. Use your own query per condition to achieve your goal.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION getStudentInfo(firstname STRING, surname STRING, schoolname STRING)
AS (
(

    case 
        when -- 1st condition
            exists(select name from `my-project.sandbox.table1` where name = concat(firstname, ' ', surname))
        then 
            (select name from `my-project.sandbox.table1` where name = concat(firstname, ' ', surname))

        when -- 2nd condition
            exists(select name from `my-project.sandbox.table2` where name = concat(firstname, ' ', surname))
        then
            (select name from `my-project.sandbox.table2` where name = concat(firstname, ' ', surname))
    end
)

);

select getStudentInfo('chris', 'paul', 'phx') as match_1,
       getStudentInfo('lebron', 'james', 'lal') as match_2,
       getStudentInfo('michael', 'jordan', 'chi') as match_3,
       getStudentInfo('tim', 'duncan', 'sas') as match_4;
```

Sample output:

[image]